# Lift to drag ratio of airliners

Tags: aerodynamics, airliner, datasets

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I am looking for lift-to-drag ratios (L/D) of different airliners. I have found a paper [1] which has some estimates of L/D for some jetliners, but it's a limited sample 
Table 3. Estimated aerodynamic characteristics of jet airplanes (L1011, a few Boeing, Douglas and Airbus). [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/where-can-i-find-data-tables-for-lift-and-drag-coefficients-of-airliners) also looks promising, but delivers airfoil numbers, not aircraft numbers, sadly. Is there any online resource or a place that might point me in the right direction?

> [1] Historical evolution of air transport productivity and efficiency
>       Rodrigo Martínez-Val, Emilio Pérez and José F. Palacín
>       Universidad Politécnica de Madrid, Madrid, Spain, 28040

Comment: In a book written by the noted aerospace engineer Henk Tennekes, (The Simple Science of Flight, MIT Press, 2009) the L/D of the Boeing 777 is mentioned 'as almost 20', and the best L/D of a Boeing 747 as 18.

Comment: @xxavier - that looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

In quotable literature, I recommend [„Aerodynamic Design of Transport Aircraft“ by Obert](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=axPvAgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR1&dq=obert%20aerodynamic%20design%20of%20transport%20aircraft). In other useful stuff, there is a very useable (but not proven by Boeing) aerodynamic model of a 787 available [on the Piano X website](http://www.lissys.demon.co.uk/samp1/index.html).

I‘d add that for any really useful analysis other than level flight, getting hold of a decent engine model giving maximum and minimum (net) thrust as well as fuel flows throughout the operating range will, in my experience, prove much harder than the aerodynamics...

Comment: With regard to thrust and fuel flow, would you find some of that info in the performance section of the flight manual (assuming that is available on line)?

Comment: @Penguin True, if that’s available. That’ll get you useable takeoff, climb and probably cruise. For descent at idle thrust, engine and particularly nacelle drag is a very important factor, and it’s not always easy to even find out whether that’s wrapped into the aerodynamic model (not often the case) or the engine model; if the latter, that particular data is hard to get by as it will not be in normal aircraft or engine documentation.